# How to fix this ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a python code, mostly based on NLTK book, for ngram POS Tagging a Gujarati language text from my GujaratiTextCorpus. I encountered a ValueError.

I am working with Python 3.7.3 in Windows 10. I use jupyter notebook through anaconda. I am a beginner in using python. I studied the answers available on stackoverflow. com to fix my ValueError, but could not solve it.

```
import nltk
f = open('C:\\Users\\BHOGAYATA\\Documents\\GujaratiPosTagging\\cts260.txt', encoding = 'utf8')
raw = f.read()
train2_sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)
text2 = nltk.Text(train2_sents)
train2_sents
import nltk
f = open('C:\\Users\\BHOGAYATA\\Documents\\GujaratiPosTagging\\txt42_sents.txt', encoding = 'utf8')
raw = f.read()
bs_sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)
text3 = nltk.Text(bs_sents)
bs_sents
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train2_sents)
unigram_tagger.tag(bs_sents)
```

I expected that the words of the two Gujarati sentences would be POS Tagged. I found the following error messages:

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5fae0b92393e> in <module>
     11 text3 = nltk.Text(bs_sents)
     12 bs_sents
---> 13 unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train2_sents)
     14 unigram_tagger.tag(bs_sents)
     15 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py in __init__(self, train, model, backoff, cutoff, verbose)
    344 
    345     def __init__(self, train=None, model=None, backoff=None, cutoff=0, verbose=False):
--> 346         NgramTagger.__init__(self, 1, train, model, backoff, cutoff, verbose)
    347 
    348     def encode_json_obj(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py in __init__(self, n, train, model, backoff, cutoff, verbose)
    293 
    294         if train:
--> 295             self._train(train, cutoff, verbose)
    296 
    297     def encode_json_obj(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py in _train(self, tagged_corpus, cutoff, verbose)
    181         fd = ConditionalFreqDist()
    182         for sentence in tagged_corpus:
--> 183             tokens, tags = zip(*sentence)
    184             for index, (token, tag) in enumerate(sentence):
    185                 # Record the event.

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says the variable you are passing have one output but you are expecting two..

Ex:

```
for a, b in [("a", "b")]:
    print("a:", a, "b:", b)

This will work 

for a, b in [("a")]:
    print("a:", a, "b:", b)

This will not work
```

Edit:

Look at your UnigramTagger
For first argument it takes a list of tagged sentences of type

```
  list(list(tuple(str, str)))
```

You are giving train2_sents of type

```
  list(tuple(str,str)
```

Where your
`list(tuple(str,str)` is same as `train2_sents`

Comment: I tried to correct my code to avoid ValueError, as suggested in the answer of my question. But I again got the same ValueError. I could not find where I am doing wrong still! my code:import nltk
f = open('C:\\Users\\BHOGAYATA\\Documents\\GujaratiPosTagging\\cts261.txt', encoding = 'utf8')
raw = f.read()
train5_sents = raw
train5_sents
I structured train5_sents as [[(str, str)]] means list(list(tuple(str, str)))

Comment: just change `train2_sents` to `list(train2_sents)` in UnigramTagger ,that what answer says,this should solve your problem, UnigramTagger is giving error as you provided your error in your question.

Comment: This is an English train2_sents: [('The', 'AT'), ('garden', 'NN'), ('is', 'BEZ'), ('clean', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]
Is it not a list(train2_sents)? I got the same ValueError for this English sentence when trying for UnigramTagger. My Gujarati train2_sents has the same structure. Where am I doing mistake? geekzeus! kindly guide me, if possible.

Comment: I could not understand how to execute list(train2_sents) in UnigramTagger.

Comment: The answer should solve your problem as the error you provided.. And to see what trouble you are having is difficult to solve without data

Comment: Here is the data of my train2_sents in UnigramTagger: [[('આદર', 'NN'), ('આપનાર', 'JJ'), ('અને', 'CC'), ('આદર', 'NN'), ('લેનાર', 'JJ'), ('એ', 'DT'), ('બેની', 'CD'), ('વચ્ચે', 'IN'), ('ચોક્કસ', 'JJ'), ('એવું', 'JJ'), ('અંતર', 'NN'), ('હોવું', 'BE'), ('જોઈએ', 'MD'), ('.', '.')], [('એ', 'DT'), ('અંતરના', 'NN'), ('અભાવમાં', 'NN'), ('આદરભાવ', 'NN'), ('શક્ય', 'JJ'), ('ન', '*'), ('બને', 'VBD'), ('.', '.')]]
It is a .txt file in Gujarati language encoded in utf8.